# How to Replace content inside custom tag in MediaWiki before saving to database?

Tags: mediawiki

First of all, I have both MW 1.16 and 1.17 set up with PHP 5.3.5, MySQL 5.5.8 and Apache 2.2.17.

I've wrote a simple $wgExtensionFunction which right now does nothing.

```
$wgExtensionFunctions[] = "wfTestExtension";

function wfTestExtension() { global $wgParser;
$wgParser->setHook("myTag", "renderTest");
}

function renderTest($input) {
   return $input;
}
```

What I want to do is, if I type `<myTag>Blah blah blah</myTag>` in the add or edit form, I want to be able to change the contents inside myTag BEFORE saving it to the database. What mechanism should I use for this? I'm assuming hooks?  For example, with the ArticleSave hook, the $text var already has the  `<myTag>` stripped out, so there's no way of trying to parse the string and figuring out what it is that was originally inside the `<myTag>`

I've spent hours trying to find something on Google, but I've almost given up. Any advice at all would be highly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/ParserBeforeStrip would work:

"Used to process the raw wiki code before any internal processing is applied"

Comment: That's what I have been trying.  The function is defined as follows:

Comment: function fnMyHook( &$parser, &$text, &$strip_state ) { ... } - However, $text doesn't give me the body of the submission.  Rather, it gives me $1 - {{SITENAME}}$1 - {{SITENAME}}{{SITENAME}}{{SITENAME}} ({{CONTENTLANGUAGE}})This page has been accessed {{PLURAL:68|once|68 times}}.About {{SITENAME}}About {{SITENAME}}

Answer (score 0):

This is another "maybe" but you could try using a combination of a template and the [{{subst:}}](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help%3aSubstitution) command (see [transclusion](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTransclusion)).

(See also [Wikis and Wikipedia](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716))